# How to set input file in Razor 3 MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor-2

I have in MVC 5 and Razor 5 page code like this:

```
<input type="file" name="file" />

<img src=@Url.Content(Model.ImagePath)" alt="Image"/>
```

When I create new item and add image by input type file it works ok. But I have this same code in Edit.cshtml and I want to set input type file from Model and id don't work. I cannot set this input file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create property in your model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string ImagePath{ get; set; }
.....


}
```

In edit View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new 
                                       { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <label for="ImageUpload">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="ImageUpload" id="ImageUpload" />
}
```

In controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(ViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        var file = Request.Files["ImageUpload"];
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0){
            var uploadDir = "~/uploads"
            var imagePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(uploadDir), file.FileName);
            var imageUrl = Path.Combine(uploadDir, file.FileName);
            file.SaveAs(imagePath);
            model.ImagePath= imageUrl;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, model.ImageUpload is null, I try to resolve this

Comment: And I add [NotMapped] form property ImageUpload

Comment: HttpPostedFileBase is abstract class and I cannot create instance of this class

Comment: Yes but I wrote that addind works, I have problem to set input file from model